# vba: iterate through type matrix and write to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, types

I need help concerning the handling of a type-matrix.
I want to create a matrix to perform certain operations in since that is much faster than doing the same in a normal worksheet. Besides I have several type matrices that operate on each other.

The part I struggle with is how I write the results to a worksheet. The only approach I have so far is to give each type in the matrix to a variant which I write to the worksheet. I guess there must be a more efficient way to write the "container_matrix" to a sheet other than to hardcode but I don't quite get it.

Is it to obvious on how to do this? Is there a way/handle to iterate through the items "container[1,2,3]" without naming them explicitly? Is the whole approach not suitable? I would like to keep the defined types "container1"

```
       Public Type container_data
            container1 As Double
            container2 As Double
            container3 As Double
        End Type

        Dim container_matrix() As container_data
        ReDim container_matrix(5)

        For int1 = 0 To 4
            
            container_matrix(int1).container1 = 10
            container_matrix(int1).container2 = 15
            container_matrix(int1).container3 = 25
        
        '**ignorance starts here:**
        Dim var1 As Variant
        ReDim var1(5, 3)

        var1(int1, 0) = container_matrix(int1).container1 
        var1(int1, 1) = container_matrix(int1).container2
        var1(int1, 2) = container_matrix(int1).container3  

        Next int1

        Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C" & 5) = var1
```

Comment: There is no way to assign arbitrary Type data to Excel. Excel is basically a 2-dimensional grid of cells each of which can contain simple data types. My advice would be to forget about your Matrices of Types and work directly with a 2-D Variant array.

Comment: That's quite a bummer. Thank you Charles, I'll write in a non-arbitrary manner in the future.